# White spaces in postFields in PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have the next code:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mydomain.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"First Name=Jhon&Last Name=bt");
curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

My problem is with the spaces in this code:

```
"First Name=Jhon&Last Name=bt"
```

I tried the next code:

$test=rawurlencode("First Name=Jhon&Last Name=bt");

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mydomain.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$test);
curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

Also I tried

$first_name=rawurlencode("First Name");

$last_name=rawurlencode("Last Name");

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mydomain.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"$first_name=Jhon&$last_name=bt");
curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

What is my error? is not working.  I need to send with the name of variables "First Name" and "Last Name".  Thanks for your help.

Comment: See my updated answer below.  Your solution might work if you remove the quotes from your variable name and propely concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

### standalone curl ENcoding.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode

### PHP urlencoding

Just encode the values first, then pass to curl as post field options.

```
$encodedValue = urlEncode("this has spaces - oh no!");
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mydomain.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , "value=" . $encodedValue);
curl_exec ($c);
curl_close ($c);
```

OR, if your *key* has the spaces:

```
 $encodedKey = urlEncode("first name");
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mydomain.com/test.php');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $encodedKey . "=Bobby");
    curl_exec ($c);
    curl_close ($c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have reviewed the link but I don't understand how to do it with my example.  I tried with urlenconde("First Name=Jhon&Last Name=bt") and is not working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: My bad, I see you are using PHP's cURL: libraries, and not the standalone curl utility.   Just leverage PHP's urlencode command.

Comment: you can 't use space in varible names, if you use space in <input name="First Name" on php side you must catch it with $_REQUEST["First_Name"]